# osmdroid coordinate snapping

Tags: android, rotation, osmdroid, utm

We are currently trying to develop a kind-of waypoint system for osmdroid. The user can place waypoints which are dependent on the building the user is currently working on.
The building data includes an angle so all lines between waypoints are multiples of 90° with respect to the original angle. For example, if the building angle (measured in comparison to a horizontal line) was 20.5°, all waypoint connections should be either 20.5°, 110.5°, 200.5° or 290.5°. When dragging a waypoint, the waypoint position should snap to the direction with the shortest angle between the touch point and any valid angle.
We worked out an algorithm which takes the touch coordinate and the last waypoint, compares the coordinates and calculates the angle between those, translates them to the origin, rotates around the minimum angle required to get a multiple of 90° and translates back. The algorithm itself seems to be working, but sometimes, the lines get "curvy" and osmdroid seems to make the waypoints take leaps when dragging them. These leaps are very small, but highly noticable when looking at the whole map.
This is the code for snapping the waypoint coordinates:

```
    public static GeoPoint getSnappedCoordinates(Waypoint w, double[] touchCoordinatesUTM, double mapRotation) {
    double[] parentWaypoint = w.getUTMCoordinatesAsDoubleArray();

    // Angle to x-axis
    double touchAngle = getAngleBetweenTwoPointsWithFixedPoint(touchCoordinatesUTM, new double[]{parentWaypoint[0], parentWaypoint[1]+1}, parentWaypoint);

    // set up valid degrees
    ArrayList<Double> validDegrees = new ArrayList<>();

    if (mapRotation < 0)
        mapRotation = 360 + mapRotation;

    double curDeg = mapRotation;

    while (!validDegrees.contains(curDeg)) {
        validDegrees.add(curDeg);
        curDeg += deg;
        curDeg %= 360;
    }

    // get closest valid angle
    double minAngleDist = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;

    for (Double d : validDegrees) {
        double curDist = Math.abs(d - touchAngle);
        if (curDist < Math.abs(minAngleDist)) {
            minAngleDist = d - touchAngle;
        }
    }

    minAngleDist = GeoTransform.deg2rad(minAngleDist);

    // translate to origin
    double translatedX = touchCoordinatesUTM[0] - parentWaypoint[0];
    double translatedY = touchCoordinatesUTM[1] - parentWaypoint[1];

    // rotate
    double[] pointR = {parentWaypoint[0] + translatedX * Math.cos(minAngleDist) - translatedY*Math.sin(minAngleDist),
            parentBeacon[1] + translatedX*Math.sin(minAngleDist) + translatedY*Math.cos(minAngleDist)};

    double[] res = GeoTransform.UTMXYToLatLon(pointR[1], pointR[0], 32, false);

    // return rotated GeoPoint
    GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint(GeoTransform.rad2deg(res[0]), GeoTransform.rad2deg(res[1]));
    return p;
}
```

The GeoTransform-class is third party and not written by us.
[This is a picture of the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fI5yV.png)
It is easily visible that the line produced by all waypoints is not straight at all, the building angle is supposed to be at around 3°. Problem ist that waypoint connection angles are nowhere near consistent. Here are some things we've already tried to eliminate the error:
1. Produce a straight line with a slope equivalent to the building angle and calculate the y position instead of rotating the coordinates
2. Rotate screen pixels instead of UTM coordinates and let the map projection translate between pixels and LatLon (to see if the error comes from GeoTransform)

Nothing helped or even changed the error at all. No matter what we did, the waypoints would take these small leaps when dragging them and the line producted by them would not be straight.
We serialize these waypoints using XML, and the LatLon coordinates look like this most of the time:

```
    <GeoPoint>
        <Lat>X.489174999999996</Lat>
        <Lon>X.404693999999999</Lon>
    </GeoPoint>
```

(replaced actual latlon values with x)
This looks like a double decimal error. Most of these waypoints have "99999" somewhere in their decimals. The above solutions didn't change anything regarding that aspect. Printing the resulting angles results in, as expected, different angles, differing up to 0.02 from 90°. Our waypoints extend the Marker class and we set the position in an OnMarkerDragListener, the implementation looks like this:

```
                double[] eventPosUTM = GeoTransform.ell2utm(eventPos.getLatitude(), eventPos.getLongitude());
            marker.setPosition(getSnappedCoordinates(marker.getConnectedEdges().get(0).getOtherWaypoint(marker), eventPosUTM, marker.getLevel().getRotationDeg()));
```

The way we are handling edges right now is more or less prototypical, and the app is supposed to be backend only and to be handled by users who know how it is implemented.
Any ideas on how to produce a straight line using multiple latlon waypoints with osmdroid when the user can drag these waypoints and the app is supposed to snap them?

Comment: There's a lot going on here, but the first thing that pops into my mind would be issues with the map projection or issues with the curvature of the Earth. For the projection - does GeoTransform use Mercator projection? For the curvature - when calculating angles are you calculating them in X,Y space and *then* translating to lat/long. That will produce straight lines on your screen, but not necessarily straight lines in terms of "walking on the Earth".

Comment: Thanks for your reply, kurtzmarc. In the official osmdroid GitHub, people just now suggested that this issue might happen due to the internal representation of GeoPoints being only ints which preserve the precision of doubles up to 6 decimals (double * 100000), which explains all the 9s in the XML.

Comment: followed here: https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/issues/356